# sed or awk remove (,) from text file

Tags: sed, awk

here the scenarios I have. the text file looks like this

```
"1","2,c","3","4,a","7"
"8","9,c","4","6,d","9"
```

so what I want is replace (,) with (-)

ex - instead of "2,c" to be "2-c" I only need the comma inside "" to be change not other comma separated used for csv file. this should change globally

Thanks!!

Comment: Why dont' you see if your source can't output tab delimited files instead? MS programs can as a sub-type of 'save as text file' Good luck ;-)!

Answer (score 4):

`s#([^"]),([^"])#\1-\2#g` works on your example:

```
$ cat example 
"1","2,c","3","4,a","7"
"8","9,c","4","6,d","9"
$ sed -E -e 's#([^"]),([^"])#\1-\2#g' example
"1","2-c","3","4-a","7"
"8","9-c","4","6-d","9"
```

The sed expression breaks down as "replace all `,` characters that aren't between two `"` characters with `-` characters".

Edit:  OP's `sed` doesn't support extended (modern) regular expressions, so here's an example with a BRE:

```
$ sed -e 's#\([^"]\),\([^"]\)#\1-\2#g' example
"1","2-c","3","4-a","7"
"8","9-c","4","6-d","9"
```

Comment: I got this error, sed -E -e 's#([^"]),([^"])#\1-\2#g' exapmple
sed: invalid option -- E

Comment: @dan, that means your version of `sed` doesn't support extended regular expressions.  You can get the same results with some more escaping.  One sec, I'll update the answer.

Comment: How about this, guys - `while read line; do echo $line | grep -o '"[A-Za-z0-9,]*"' | sed 's/,/-/g' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/\n/g'; done < test.txt`? :-)

Comment: @Vlad, why `echo` and `grep` together?

Comment: @Carl: just for fun, and why writing something like that at all? :)

Comment: How about `'s#\([^"]\),#\1-#g'`

Comment: @Beta, that looks like it would work too.  And simpler to boot!

Answer (score 1):

I have done alot of global replaces and have an alternative,you might just be making life too complicated here.  If you use the emacs editor you can just do three global replace statements:

M-x repl-s "," "--" replace the "," with a unique string, then just
M-x repl-s '    where you replace all remaining ' with a space, then you just put the other comma's back with

M-x repl-s "--" ","    I know this isn't strictly a sed example but I thought it might provide a nice alternative.  I sometimes prefer to just hop in a text editor rather than sed-ing everything up, but that might just be me.